# Authentication in local debug build of Azure App Service results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, local

I'm trying to debug an Azure App Service .Net backend project that has authentication/authorization enabled for database API access. Attempting to use it results in 401 Unauthorized.

I have set, as suggested elsewhere, the MobileServiceClient object's AlternateLoginHost to point to the remote Azure service so that it would be relied on. In the App Service project, I have copied SigningKey from the Kudu settings page (https://[servicename].scm.azurewebsites.net) and have set ValidAudience and ValidIssuer to the app service address (https://[servicename].azurewebsites.net/). ConfigureMobileApp() calls UseAppServiceAuthentication with the Web.config local values, then UseWebApi is called.

I've looked at the requests and responses with Fiddler, and they have the X-ZUMO-AUTH token. I've switched between the local vs. remote service, and the remote service will accept the token while the local service rejects it.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Did I miss something? Is there anything else to check?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is an incompatibility in the Azure App Service library with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v5. I discovered this by trying to use the token validation method manually, which presented a TypeLoadException for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken.

Unfortunately, the exception doesn't appear in the debug log during normal debugging.

This incompatibility appears to be a known issue, but the dependency in the NuGet package doesn't note it. (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/195)